# C++ How can I call superclass constructor with two parameters from derived class constructor with one parameter?

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

For example, this:

```
class shape {
private:
    int height;
    int width;
public:
    shape(int h, int w) {
        height = h;
        width = w;
    }
    void display() {
        std::cout << height << "\t" << width << std::endl;
    }
};

class square : public shape {
public:
    square(int d) {
        shape(d, d);
    }
};
```

I get the following error message:

```
no default constructor exists for class "shape"
```

Why is this happening? I get that it wants a default constructor for the base class, I want to know why it wants so, and if I change the syntax of the `square` constructor into initialization list, `square(int d): shape(d, d){}`. the program compiles successfully. What is the difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply by calling the constructor like this:

```
class square : public shape {
public:
    square(int d): shape(d, d)
    {
    }
};
```

It is important that you call the constructor *before* the body of the constructor of the derived class. You should also initialize your member variables *before* the constructor body.

If you will not do that, the default initialization of all objects will be done and after that a assignment will be done as second step. In your example, you first try to use default initialization of your parent class which is not possible, because you have no default constructor.

More on this topic can be found here:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list

Comment: Yeah I included it in the question. I want to know why it doesn't happen the other way. What is the difference between this form and the form I wrote.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the difference?

For the 1st sample, the base class subobject will be default initialized at first (and then cause the error). `shape(d, d);` inside the constructor's body is just creating a temporary `shape`, which has nothing to do with the current object.

For the 2nd one, i.e. `square(int d): shape(d, d){}`, with the usage of [member initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list#Explanation), the base class subobject is initialized by the constructor `shape::shape(int h, int w)`.

> Before the compound statement that forms the function body of the constructor begins executing, initialization of all direct bases, virtual bases, and non-static data members is finished. Member initializer list is the place where non-default initialization of these objects can be specified. For members that cannot be default-initialized, such as members of reference and const-qualified types, member initializers must be specified.

Comment: I would add: C++ is not Java. While in Java you can call the parent constructor in the first statement of the body and it will be OK, that is not the case in C++. In C++ there is no notion of "first instruction". When the program enters the derived class constructor body, all the parent stuff is already initialized (using the default constructor by default)

Answer (score 0):

when `parameterized constructor` is defined `shape(int h, int w) { }`  and `no default constructor` is defined explicitly then compiler will not call the `default constructor` thats why it shows the error.

So either add the `default constructor` or add like you suggested

```
square(int d): shape(d, d){ 
 /* ... */
}
```